# SQL - predicate on an ordered series of numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have several rows (ordered by Date) of which one column contains following data:

```
1
1
1
0
0
1
0
1
1
1
```

etc.
How can I select the count of 1s until next 0 is reached, after which reset the counter. For example, the query should return the following data:

```
1 
1 
1 3
0  
0  
1 1
0 
1 
1 
1 3
```

Actually, I don't need actual data, I'm ok if the query returns only aggregate/count. I just included first column to for easier understanding.
I'm running PostgreSQL 9.5. However, it would be interesting how this problem can be solved for other DBs as well.

Thanks

Comment: is there any other column to specify the order?

Comment: Hi, yes, something like ORDER BY Date

Comment: You need a column that specifies the ordering.  By default SQL tables are unordered.

Comment: Sure, I updated my post. The rows are ordered by Date column, which is as the name says datetime field :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this SQL I assume column c1 is a sequence for the dates

```
drop table if exists t5;
create table t5 (c1 int primary key, c2 int);

insert into t5 values (1, 1);
insert into t5 values (2, 1);
insert into t5 values (3, 1);
insert into t5 values (4, 0);
insert into t5 values (5, 0);
insert into t5 values (6, 1);
insert into t5 values (7, 0);
insert into t5 values (8, 1);
insert into t5 values (9, 1);
insert into t5 values (10, 1);

select grp, max(cnt) from (
    with recursive t(id, cnt, grp) as (
        select c1, c2, 1
        from t5
        where c1 = 1
        union all
        select c1, 
               -- if next is 1 increment existing count else set it to zero
               case when b.c2 = 1 then cnt+1 else 0 end, 
               -- if 0 change group else retain group [0 to 1 will retain group] 
               -- as long as '1' to '0' changes the group we are good
               case when b.c2 = 1 then grp else grp+1 end
        from t5 b, t
        where b.c1 = id + 1
    ) 
    select * from t
) t  group by grp having max(cnt) > 0 order by grp
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a partial solution for SQL Server 2008 R2, but should implement on other databases. `ones` is your original table with an `id` key field that reflects the order of the data (1, 2, 3, etc). `flag` holds the `1` and `0` entries. It groups the data by counting rows containing flag=0 that appear before each row. Each run of `1` will count an increasing number of zeroes coming before it, so you can use that to uniquely identify each run of `1`.
It doesn't provide a running count but gives you a summary count for each run of `1`s.

```
create table ones_summary ( PreviousZeros int )

insert ones_summary
select ( select count(*) as N from ones t2 where t2.id < t1.id and t2.flag = 0 ) as PreviousZeros
 from ones t1 
 where t1.flag = 1

select PreviousZeros, count(*) 
from ones_summary
group by PreviousZeros
```